# Perform Several Categorizations in a Single Query or Report

Tags: ms-access

I was asked to create a report on adding up how many customers we have based on several different categories, like gender, age range, annual income range, and so on.  These are distinct, unrelated partitions on the data, not just refinements.  It appears that Access can only handle one partition in each query or report.

For example, if I use the grouping function in Reports, I will begin with (male) and (female), then proceed with subgroups (male, 18 - 35), (female, 18 - 35) and so on.  Rather I need to count how many male and female customers there are.  Then, forget about gender and count how many customers there are in each age group.  Then, forget about age and proceed with a new partition and so on.

It will be awkward to write a new query or report each time.  If nothing works, I am thinking to just export the counts into an Excel template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to write an Excel template, Access is perfectly capable of doing this by itself.

The most usual way to do this is using conditional sums. E.g.:

```
SELECT Sum(Iif([sex] = "male", 1, 0)) As CountMales, Sum(Iif([sex] = "female", 1, 0)) As CountFemales, Sum(Iif([sex] = "male" And [age] Between 18 And 35, 1, 0) As CountMales18To35, etc
From MyTable
```

Comment: I was hoping to use the full arsenal of Access, but it looked more like plugging out desired entries via SQL.  Nonetheless, it works.  TY!